High-level sun sensor modelling for satellite
I am searching for some references on how to model at high level a sensor in terms of the statistical interpretation of the errors (bias, noise, ecc). Do someone have any reference (books or papers) regarding the topic?

I am unable to provide much detail as an answer,
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281628063_Modeling_Inertial_Sensor_Errors_Using_Autoregressive_AR_Models
But this PDF should help.

Link only answers as seldomly helpful.  Please provide a summary of the useful information from your link.

Add the link as a comment to the question if you don't want or have time to add an useful explanation of the link.
